# Tizen Gear 2 to Android Native Java App Communication

Tags: javascript, java, android, tizen

I'm trying to send data between my gear 2 web JavaScript app and a android native Java app. I am extremely new to Java programming but very familiar with JavaScript.

all the examples of this I've seen online have an issue with the com.samsung lines of code in the Java.... for example

```
<service android:name="com.samsung.android.example.helloaccessoryprovider.service.HelloAccessoryProviderService" >
```

I'm using Android Studios....

If anyone is able to provide a working example that I can use as a template I would be most grateful :) because none of the online "Working" examples I've tried seem to work....

Comment: What problems are you facing ?

Comment: quite a vast amount, I suspect mostly because I'm not used to Java ... but I think most issues are being caused by that com.samsung url thing, not being seen as valid at times such as imports... thats why I was hoping for a working example

Comment: Where did you find this app ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a working sample of the Companion Operation?

You can learn the Companion operation from Samsung Developer Public Web Site, below.

http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app

and You can get a working sample here for various purpose, below.
http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/samples/companion

Good luck to you.